# Android Access SQLite Database of other application

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i try to access a database of another application, i want to insert data on that database from my application. I test it on my phone (rooted) but i get errors. Can anyone help me?

```
12-30 00:01:27.315: E/SQLiteLog(10477): (14) os_unix.c:30241: (13) open(/data/data/com.otherapplication/databases/records.db) - 
12-30 00:01:27.376: E/SQLiteDatabase(10477): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.otherapplication/databases/records.db'.
12-30 00:01:27.376: E/SQLiteDatabase(10477):    at com.test.MySQLiteOpenHelper.insertData(MySQLiteOpenHelper.java:28)
12-30 00:01:27.376: E/SQLiteDatabase(10477):    at com.test.MainActivity.test(MainActivity.java:45)
12-30 00:01:27.446: E/AndroidRuntime(10477):    at com.test.MySQLiteOpenHelper.insertData(MySQLiteOpenHelper.java:28)
12-30 00:01:27.446: E/AndroidRuntime(10477):    at com.test.MainActivity.test(MainActivity.java:45)
```

Here are the files, **MySQLiteOpenHelper.java :**

```java
package com.test;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MySQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "/data/data/com.otherapplication/databases/records.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void insertData() { 
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
        values.put("id", "testvalue");
        database.insert("table", null, values);
        database.close(); 
        }


}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MySQLiteOpenHelper controller = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(this);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void test(View v) {
        controller.insertData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Only the application itself can access its local data. If you want to connect 2 apps together, you need to use exported DataProviders.

Comment: i want to access the database of other application which i didn't created it, it isn't possible?

Comment: No. Unless that application saves it's database in the memory card. Which is highly unlikely.

Comment: so is there any way to do this thing which i want? ex. copy the database to somewhere then insert the data after replace it with the other?

Comment: No sane application would allow that. Think of all the data you could steal...

Comment: but manually i can do it, for example i copy the database with file manager i open it, insert the data, save it then replace it with the application's. i just want to do this with my own application quickly, but as you say it isn't possible

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution:

I did chmod 777 to that application's 'databases' folder and that database file. And now i can insert data from my application.